# Neo4j: too many open files error on linux for a huge dataset

Tags: java, linux, neo4j, lucene

Dear Neo4j programmers,

I've imported a huge dataset with 33M nodes and 144M relationships into `Neo4j`.  Thanks to Neo4j developers, "`neo4j-importer`" was very efficient. However, I'm getting (**Too many open files**) errors.

I'm using `Neo4j 3.x Java API` running on a linux machine and dataset volume is **9GB**. Fortunately, I've increased the hard/soft open files limit to 40,000. So, right now `ulimit -n` shows me 40k.

However, I keep getting the following error (I've summarized the exceptions trace):

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: focusSetIDS.txt (Too many open files)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@5b61d558' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception closing multiple resources
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /xxx/idsForExp/idsAttackDB/schema/label/lucene/labelStore/1: Too many open files
```

Please guide me by answering even one of the following questions:

1. Is there anyway to turn off some Neo4j features like `lucene` to not get this error? In fact, I didn't index anything explicitly and I've just imported node/relationships using `neo4j-importer` (In the program, I may add/remove some relationships but I won't manipulate nodes anyway).
2. Should I increase it to even more than 40k simultaneous open files? (I'm not the administrator of the system)
3. Is it possible that this error came from memory limit? (I've allocated 50GB for JVM and initialize the data graph like below.)
4. Do you have any other suggestion?

---

```
File storeDir = new File(dataGraphPath);
dataGraph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(storeDir)
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "6g").newGraphDatabase();
```

Comment: There's a limit on how many open files a process can maintain.
The P.D.T is of limited size, 256 entries. Hence, a process can at most have 256 files open. (Entry 0 is for stdin, entry 1 is for stdout, entry 2 for stderr) so not exactly 256. Perhaps that is your problem.

Comment: @TonyTannous. Thanks for reply. Any high-level solution for that? I didn't get what is the relation of the 3 entries and 256. Can I remove this limitation? What is P.D.T?

Comment: PDT = A Process Descriptor Table. 
What I meant to say is, there's a limitation on the number of open files a process can have. It might not be your problem, but its a good piece of information for you as you intend to open a lot of files.

Comment: You might want to repeat the ingest and monitor the number of files / threads using the lsof piped through wc commands. That way you can see whether it truly is reaching your 40k limit